# Java Streams, skipping the first item in each list in a Stream of List of elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a number of input tables in a list, each input table has a header row which I would like to ignore.

Minimal example:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("header", "v1", "v2", "v3");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("header", "a1", "a2");
List<String> c = Arrays.asList("header", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4");

List<List<String>> data = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);

List<String> result = data.stream()
    .map(t -> t.subList(1, t.size()))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a "nicer" way to skip the header row then using `map` on each table?

Note: I am using Java 8 and unable to migrate to a newer JDK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `skip()`:

```
List<String> result = data.stream()
    .flatMap(t -> t.stream().skip(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How did I not see that!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either call `stream` on the the result of `subList()`:

```
List<String> result = data.stream()
    .flatMap(t -> t.subList(1, t.size()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, alternatively, call `skip` on the inner stream:

```
List<String> result = data.stream()
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream().skip(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I didnt see that either.  Though I have a slight preference for the `flatMap` version

Comment: @Gavin It has to be flatMap either way :) - I had a typo

Comment: its one of those days :)  I what I meant to say is I slightly prefer the one that uses `skip` :)

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way is to use filter as below,

```
List<String> result = data.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(e->!e.equals("header"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It does have a certain clarity though